# Directory tree for storing images - does it actually improve efficiency?

Tags: sql, database, image, storage

Something i'm looking into doing is re-designing the file structure we have, I am planning on splitting everything into folders so that it is easy to navigate to the images of a precise product, however I was curious as to whether or not splitting files into directorys will actually improve the speed and effiency in which the web browser locates and calls the images? Or is this simply only a benefit to the user in terms of being able to find what we need much quicker than our current layout which is one big folder with every image stored in.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on the number of files you are talking about as well as the operating system and disk format.

There is quite a bit of anecdotal evidence that large folders under NTFS degrades performance, to which I can personally attest as well.  If the files number in the thousands you will likely benefit from splitting things up into separate folders, with the additional advantage of having things better organized.

Other formats and operating systems may or may not have such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Moving things into folders is not going to significantly affect speed for the serving of images, especially if you just use folders for storage right now anyways.  Switching to a database would affect the speed, but just changing your folder structure shouldn't do that.  The positive aspects are that the files are easier for humans to understand.  The danger in saving images separate from the database is that image file names can be altered or the information connecting them to the db record could be changed somehow, orphaning the image.  Any additional information, such as using subfolders, helps prevent that from happening.